# How to Disable message: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode?

Tags: linux, centos

I have a network monitoring app which, by design, sets the interface in and out of promiscuous mode quite often.

This results in a lot of messages littering /var/log/messages:

```
Nov 23 15:13:49  kernel: device eth1 left promiscuous mode
Nov 23 16:04:40  kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 23 17:17:28  kernel: device eth1 left promiscuous mode
Nov 23 17:36:33  kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 23 17:43:30  kernel: device eth1 left promiscuous mode
Nov 23 17:43:45  kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 23 17:44:51  kernel: device eth1 left promiscuous mode
Nov 23 17:45:06  kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
Nov 23 17:47:36  kernel: device eth1 left promiscuous mode
Nov 23 17:47:39  kernel: device eth1 entered promiscuous mode
```

Is there a way to turn off these messages?  (Centos 6.6 with 3.10 kernel)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default CentOS 6.6 uses rsyslogd, so why don't you [filter these messages out by content](http://www.rsyslog.com/doc/v8-stable/configuration/filters.html) like this:

```
vi  /etc/rsyslog.d/zz-promiscuous.conf
```

Here:

```
:msg, contains, "device eth1 entered promiscuous mode"   ~  # tilde ignores the message
:msg, contains, "device eth1 left promiscuous mode"      ~
```

Then:

```
service rsyslog restart
```

Works for me.

Unfortunately there is no logic in kernel [net/core/dev.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/net/core/dev.c?v=3.11#L4604) to get rid of these messages. Too bad, this would be a preferred clean way.